# How do you show a current table row selection when there's multiple table pages?

Tags: gui-design, tables, selection, status

How do you show that a table row (data choice within that row) has been selected in a multi-page table if you are viewing another page within the table that does not contain the selected row?

Comment: Is the user only able to make a single row selection? Or can they select multiple rows across multiple pages?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an option where you carry over the selected row might be ideal?

Think like a fixed banner at the top of each table page containing your row saying something akin to "you have selected:" and the row underneath.